# Using powershell to get the "Audit Policy" security setting value

Tags: powershell, audit-logging

I am trying to use Powershell (auditpol) to query the security setting values of the Audit Policy items. So far with all the auditpol commands, I only able to get the subcategories value instead.

`auditpol /get /category:*`

So far I could only get the list of the 9 items without the success/failure/no auditing values using:

`auditpol /list/category`

Could there be a command/flag that I might have left out for auditpol or is there any other command for me to retrieve the policies and its relevant security setting values?

[Policy and values that I would like to query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLkyB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, `auditpol` only manages the settings that are in effect when the "Advanced Audit Policy Configuration" feature is enabled.

To query the "classic" audit policy, you will need to use the [LSA Policy Win32 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secmgmt/management-functions#lsa-policy-functions) to:

1. Open the local security policy using `LsaOpenPolicy()`
2. Query the audit settings using `LsaQueryPolicyInformation()`
3. Translate the results to something readable.

---

The following example uses `Add-Type` to compile a C# type that in turn does all of the above:

```
$AuditPolicyReader = Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AuditPolicyReader
{
    [Flags()]
    public enum AuditPolicySetting
    {
        Unknown =  -1,
        None    = 0x0,
        Success = 0x1,
        Failure = 0x2
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING
    {
        public UInt16 Length;
        public UInt16 MaximumLength;
        public IntPtr Buffer;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int Length;
        public IntPtr RootDirectory;
        public LSA_UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
        public IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
        public IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;
    }

    public struct POLICY_AUDIT_EVENTS_INFO
    {
        public bool AuditingMode;
        public IntPtr EventAuditingOptions;
        public Int32 MaximumAuditEventCount;
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    static extern uint LsaQueryInformationPolicy(IntPtr PolicyHandle, uint InformationClass, out IntPtr Buffer);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = true)]
    static extern uint LsaOpenPolicy(ref LSA_UNICODE_STRING SystemName, ref LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes, uint DesiredAccess, out IntPtr PolicyHandle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint LsaClose(IntPtr ObjectHandle);

    public static Dictionary<string, AuditPolicySetting> GetClassicAuditPolicy()
    {
        // Create dictionary to hold the audit policy settings (the key order here is important!!!)
        var settings = new Dictionary<string, AuditPolicySetting>
        {
            {"System", AuditPolicySetting.Unknown},
            {"Logon", AuditPolicySetting.Unknown},
            {"Object Access", AuditPolicySetting.Unknown},
            {"Privilige Use", AuditPolicySetting.Unknown},
            {"Detailed Tracking", AuditPolicySetting.Unknown},
            {"Policy Change", AuditPolicySetting.Unknown},
            {"Account Management", AuditPolicySetting.Unknown},
            {"Directory Service Access", AuditPolicySetting.Unknown},
            {"Account Logon", AuditPolicySetting.Unknown},
        };

        // Open local machine security policy
        IntPtr polHandle;
        LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES aObjectAttributes = new LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES();
        aObjectAttributes.Length = 0;
        aObjectAttributes.RootDirectory = IntPtr.Zero;
        aObjectAttributes.Attributes = 0;
        aObjectAttributes.SecurityDescriptor = IntPtr.Zero;
        aObjectAttributes.SecurityQualityOfService = IntPtr.Zero;

        var systemName = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING();
        uint desiredAccess = 2; // we only need the audit policy, no need to request anything else
        var res = LsaOpenPolicy(ref systemName, ref aObjectAttributes, desiredAccess, out polHandle);
        if (res != 0)
        {
            if(res == 0xC0000022)
            {
                // Access denied, needs to run as admin
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Failed to open LSA policy because of insufficient access rights");
            }
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to open LSA policy with return code '0x{0:X8}'", res));
        }
        try
        {
            // now that we have a valid policy handle, we can query the settings of the audit policy
            IntPtr outBuffer;
            uint policyType = 2; // this will return information about the audit settings
            res = LsaQueryInformationPolicy(polHandle, policyType, out outBuffer);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to query LSA policy information with '0x{0:X8}'", res));
            }

            // copy the raw values returned by LsaQueryPolicyInformation() to a local array;
            var auditEventsInfo = Marshal.PtrToStructure<POLICY_AUDIT_EVENTS_INFO>(outBuffer);
            var values = new int[auditEventsInfo.MaximumAuditEventCount];                
            Marshal.Copy(auditEventsInfo.EventAuditingOptions, values, 0, auditEventsInfo.MaximumAuditEventCount);

            // now we just need to translate the provided values into our settings dictionary
            var categoryIndex = settings.Keys.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                settings[categoryIndex[i]] = (AuditPolicySetting)values[i];
            }

            return settings;
        }
        finally
        {
            // remember to release policy handle
            LsaClose(polHandle);
        }
    }
}
'@ -PassThru |Where-Object Name -eq AuditPolicyReader
```

Now we can call `GetClassicAuditPolicy()` (remember to run this from an elevated prompt):

```
PS ~> $AuditPolicyReader::GetClassicAuditPolicy()
Key                                 Value
---                                 -----
System                               None
Logon                    Success, Failure
Object Access                        None
Privilige Use                        None
Detailed Tracking                    None
Policy Change                     Success
Account Management       Success, Failure
Directory Service Access             None
Account Logon                        None
```

Comment: How can I extend this to get the info for each subcategory (set via auditpol)? $process_creation_guid = '{0CCE922B-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030}'; auditpol /set /subcategory:"$process_creation_guid" /failure:enable

Answer (score 1):

`auditpol` only returns the [Advanced audit policy configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn452415(v=ws.11)). These settings can be found in the UI under `Security Settings > Advanced Audit Policy Configuration > System Audit Policies`

The legacy audit policy your screenshot shows were mostly done away with after Windows Server 2003/Windows Vista. Note the warnings in the policy properties or on the MS [compatibility page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn319079(v=ws.11)):

For advanced policies, you can use `/r` to get a csv-formatted table:

```sh
auditpol /get /category:'Account Logon' /r | ConvertFrom-Csv | 
Format-Table 'Policy Target',Subcategory,'Inclusion Setting'
```

```
Policy Target Subcategory                        Inclusion Setting
------------- -----------                        -----------------
System        Kerberos Service Ticket Operations No Auditing      
System        Other Account Logon Events         No Auditing      
System        Kerberos Authentication Service    No Auditing      
System        Credential Validation              No Auditing
```

For legacy audit policies:

```
secedit.exe /export /areas SECURITYPOLICY /cfg filename.txt
```

```
[Event Audit]
AuditSystemEvents = 0
AuditLogonEvents = 0
AuditObjectAccess = 0
AuditPrivilegeUse = 0
AuditPolicyChange = 0
AuditAccountManage = 0
AuditProcessTracking = 0
AuditDSAccess = 0
AuditAccountLogon = 0
```

Requires that it hasn't been disabled. Check in the registry:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name SCENoApplyLegacyAuditPolicy
```

Comment: The output format depends on the OS language. Therefore I cannot recommend this for a global solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that gives you a list of all categories and subcategories with their current audit-status. I made it a bit longer than really needed to add the local names of each object. Also see some usage-samples at the end of the code.

```
# getting the audit policy settings for each subcategory
# works for any OS language

cls
Remove-Variable * -ea 0
$ErrorActionPreference = 'stop'
#requires -runasadmin

$dll = [string]::Join("`r`n", '[DllImport("advapi32.dll")]', 'public static extern bool') 
$auditpol = Add-Type -Name 'AuditPol' -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru -MemberDefinition "
$dll AuditEnumerateCategories(out IntPtr catList, out uint count);
$dll AuditLookupCategoryName(Guid catGuid, out string catName);
$dll AuditEnumerateSubCategories(Guid catGuid, bool all, out IntPtr subList, out uint count);
$dll AuditLookupSubCategoryName(Guid subGuid, out String subName);
$dll AuditQuerySystemPolicy(Guid subGuid, uint count, out IntPtr policy);
$dll AuditFree(IntPtr buffer);"

Add-Type -TypeDefinition "
using System;
public struct AUDIT_POLICY_INFORMATION {
    public Guid AuditSubCategoryGuid;
    public UInt32 AuditingInformation;
    public Guid AuditCategoryGuid;
}"

function getPolicyInfo($sub) {
    # get policy info for one subcategory:
    $pol = new-object AUDIT_POLICY_INFORMATION
    $size = $ms::SizeOf($pol)
    $ptr  = $ms::AllocHGlobal($size)
    $null = $ms::StructureToPtr($pol, $ptr, $false)
    $null = $auditpol::AuditQuerySystemPolicy($sub, 1, [ref]$ptr)
    $pol  = $ms::PtrToStructure($ptr, [type][AUDIT_POLICY_INFORMATION])
    $null = $ms::FreeHGlobal($ptr)
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        category = $pol.AuditCategoryGuid
        success  = [bool]($pol.AuditingInformation -band 1)
        failure  = [bool]($pol.AuditingInformation -band 2)
    }
}

# (optional) get GUID and local name of all categories:
$ms = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]
$count = [uint32]0
$buffer = [IntPtr]::Zero
$size = $ms::SizeOf([type][guid])
$null = $auditpol::AuditEnumerateCategories([ref]$buffer,[ref]$count)
$ptr = [int64]$buffer
$name = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$catList = @{}
foreach($id in 1..$count) {
    $guid = $ms::PtrToStructure([IntPtr]$ptr,[type][guid])
    $null = $auditpol::AuditLookupCategoryName($guid,[ref]$name)
    $catList[$guid] = $name
    $ptr += $size
}
$null = $auditpol::AuditFree($buffer)

# get all subcategories (with optional name):
$guid = [guid]::Empty
$null = $auditpol::AuditEnumerateSubCategories($guid, $true, [ref]$buffer, [ref]$count)
$ptr = [int64]$buffer
$subList = @{}
foreach($id in 1..$count) {
    $guid = $ms::PtrToStructure([IntPtr]$ptr,[type][guid])
    $null = $auditpol::AuditLookupSubCategoryName($guid,[ref]$name)
    $pol  = getPolicyInfo $guid
    $data = [psCustomObject]@{
        category = $catList[$pol.category]
        subcategory = $name
        success = $pol.success
        failure = $pol.failure
    }
    $subList[$guid.guid] = $data
    $ptr += $size
}
$null = $auditpol::AuditFree($buffer)

# listing all subCategories and their audit settings:
$subList.Values | sort category, subcategory | ft -AutoSize

# gettings the audit-settings for a given subcategory-GUID (without '{}'):
$process_creation_guid = '0CCE922B-69AE-11D9-BED3-505054503030'
$subList[$process_creation_guid]
```

Comment: For a GUID-list of all categories/subcategories see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/auditing-constants